# How can I query all documents that contain a string of text from the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a search bar where a user can search through a collection.

I've been trying to figure out how to use Collection.find() to query for all documents that contain the value of the input, but I really just don't know where to start.

Comment: The [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) is very detailed and a very good start. Related to your issue you should especially read about [Publications and Data Loading](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html). Please also add your code or this question may be voted to be closed as being too borad.

Comment: If you are using an input field, you will need to escape the string to form a regular expression, which you can then pass to `Collection.find()`. One technique is to structure your data to include a `search` field, which is a concatenation of all of the other fields, and makes your search expression simpler.

Comment: If you are familiar with indexing, you can implement a text index on the string fields of the collection, and use that to have 'google-like' searching of your documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/